# Columnas no se muestran en tabla "footable"

Tags: html, jquery

```js
function abrir(idOferta) {
    $('#unidades').val(1);
    modal('{{ path("neumaticos") }}/ficha/' + idOferta);
}
jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable();
});
```

```html
<table id="neumaticos-resutl" class="table table-striped table-responsive" data-filtering="true" data-paging="true">
        <thead>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs" data-visible="true"></th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs" data-visible="true">{{ "Referencia"|trans }}</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs" data-visible="true">{{ "Descripcion"|trans }}</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs" data-visible="true">{{ "Marca"|trans }}</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs" data-visible="true">{{ "Precio"|trans }}</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs" data-visible="true">{{ "Stock.almacen"|trans }}</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs" data-visible="true">{{ "Stock.total"|trans }}</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for neumatico in neumaticos %}
            {% if neumatico.stock > 0 or (neumatico.stock == 0 and neumatico.baja is null) %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="abrir('{{ neumatico.referencia }}');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="abrir('{{ neumatico.referencia }}');">{{ neumatico.referencia }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ neumatico.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ neumatico.marca }}</td>
                <td>
                    {{ neumatico.precio|number_format(2, ',', '.') }}€
                </td>
                <td>{% if neumatico.almacen > 4 %}
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/green.png') }}" title="{{ "Stock.verde"|trans }}" />
                    {% elseif neumatico.almacen > 0 %}
                        {{ "Quedan"|trans ~ " " ~ neumatico.almacen ~ " " ~ "unidades"|trans }}
                    {% elseif neumatico.almacen == 0 and neumatico.minimo > 0 %}
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/blue.png') }}" title="{{ "Stock.azul"|trans }}" />
                    {% else %}
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/yellow.png') }}" title="{{ "Stock.amarillo"|trans }}" />
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% if neumatico.stock > 0 %}
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/green.png') }}" title="{{ "Stock.verde"|trans }}" />
                    {% elseif neumatico.stock == 0 and neumatico.minimo > 0 %}
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/blue.png') }}" title="{{ "Stock.azul"|trans }}" />
                    {% else %}
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/yellow.png') }}" title="{{ "Stock.amarillo"|trans }}" />
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

este es el enlace a la documentación
https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/basic/hiding-columns.html

si no pongo el `data-breakpoints="xs"` da igual que sea XS o cualquier otro, la tabla funciona pero no muestra los enlaces de los `<td>` de abajo, si no pongo `data-breakpoints="xs"` la tabla no se visualiza con el estilo de footable...

Comment: ¿Dónde está definida la función `abrir`?

Comment: Editado, esta en el mismo archivo que la funcion del footable y la tabla.

Comment: Tocando un poco las cosas me  he dado cuenta de que al aplicar footables lo que deja de funcionar es el código html dentro de los `<td>` ya que si acepta texto plano, pero al poner un `<a>` también lo representa como texto plano.

Comment: La solución ha sido actualizar el plugin, estaba usando la versión 3.0.1 y la actual es la 3.1.6 y justamente en la que tenía había ese fallo